# Is it possible a single user review a answer two times?

Tags: discussion, support

I have faced a situation where i can able to review a single question two times both in

**First Posts**

and

**Late Answers**

is it a bug?

Comment: No, this is a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @mpdonadio comments.

This is a feature.